# Shouldn't the topological space be $T_1$ for the Skyscraper sheaf to be a sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory

> Prove that the Skyscraper sheaf is a sheaf

A Skyscraper sheaf is defined in the following way:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, with $p\in X$, and $S$ is a set. Let $i_p:p\to X$ be the inclusion. Then $i_{p,*}S(U)=S$ if $p\in U$, and $\{e\}$ if $p\notin U$

Shouldn't the space $X$ be $T_1$ for this to be a sheaf?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: @Nitrogen- If two functions are the same over all open sets, then they have to be the same. Hence, if the space was not $T_1$, then it's possible that given two points $p,q\in X$, there would not exist an open set containing one and not the other. Hence, $i_p$ and $i_q$ would be the same on all sets, and hence would be considered the same maps, although they really are not

Comment: @Ayush: this is not an issue. What is true is that if $p$ and $q$ are both contained in the same open sets, then skyscraper sheaves at $p$ and skyscraper sheaves at $q$ are the same sheaves on $X$. But there's nothing preventing them from being sheaves.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan- I'm sorry I don't quite understand. Sheaves? I thought we were talking about a single sheaf. Are you saying that the maps $i_p$ and $i_q$ are the same, although they were indexed by different points?

Comment: @Ayush: skyscraper sheaves can have any stalk you like; there isn't a single sheaf called "the skyscraper sheaf." I'm saying that the maps $i_p$ and $i_q$ aren't the same, but that the skyscraper sheaves you get by pushing forward along them might be (if $p$ and $q$ are contained in the same open sets). Have you tried just checking the sheaf axioms? There is absolutely no need for $X$ to be Hausdorff.

Comment: Your confusion may come from the fact that if $X$ is not $T_1$, then the "skyscraper sheaf" given by this definition may not have the property that its only nontrivial stalk is at $p$, which is the inspiration behind the name "skyscraper".  But it is still a sheaf.